# Рисование треугольника

Tags: алгоритм

Решаю задачу с Дейтов: нужно нарисовать прямоугольный треугольник с помощью символа * и цикла for. Как это осуществить идей нету пока. Просьба натолкнуть на идею. Код просьба не кидать. Треугольник должен быть закрашен полностью.

Comment: А язык какой?

Answer (score 4):

см. алгоритм Брезенхема для рисования линий, аналогично - для треугольников

Answer (score 3):

Интересная задача. :) Сейчас такие задания есть на ЕГЭ по информатике в части C. ;)

Я лишь объединю уже написанные ответы.
В общем случае, когда треугольник занимает общее положение (т.е. как-то повёрнут в пространстве) всё просто: определяем тангенс угла наклона каждой стороны (т.е. дельта Y делить на дельта X. Это будет коэффициент для уравнений прямых, задающих эти самые стороны), наименьший и наибольший X, и наименьший и наибольший Y (т.е. определяем квадрат, к который вписан наш треугольник). Затем запускаем цикл от наименьшего X до наибольшего X, а внутри него цикл от наименьшего Y до наибольшего Y. И внутри второго проверяем, принадлежит ли текущая точка заданному треугольнику. Т.е. Для текущей точки (а точка, это координаты X и Y) выполняются ли условия: правее или на левой грани, левее или на правой грани, выше или на нижней грани. (вообще левая/правая/нижняя - это пример... зависит от того, как он у вас повёрнут.) Важен принцип: точка должна быть внутри треугольника, рисуемого тремя прямыми по уравнению y=kx+b. И при проверке Вы подставляете свои X и Y вместо соответствующих переменных в неравенство (т.к. нужно, чтобы треугольник был не просто нарисован, но и закрашен, то надо неравенства)... А коэффициент k для каждой прямой мы высчитали в начале (тангенс угла наклона сторон).

Если треугольник занимает частное положение (т.е. одна из граней параллельна одной из осей), то алгоритм упрощается: нужно использовать только два уравнения (а третье: Y=const; например). Т.е. мы так же берём два цикла, один внутри другого, и проверяем, принадлежит ли точка треугольнику или нет.

Если по-прежнему непонятно, то: возьмите бумажку, нарисуйте систему координат, на ней прямоугольный треугольник и прикиньте, что да как... принцип в том, что мы перебираем все точки и определяем, какие нужно закрашивать, а какие нет (а в вашем случае ставить звёздочки).

Answer (score 2):

Если треугольник со сторонами a и b, предположим a по вертикали и b по горизонтали, приращение горизонтального количества * меняется от 0 до b c шагом b/a.

Comment: Добавлю, что b/a нужно округлить, к большему или к меньшему значению.

Comment: Шаг не надо округлять, также как и реально полученное количество, иначе накопится ошибка. Округлять нужно только количество отображаемых *. Либо нужно делать так, либо каждый раз высчитывать количество *  округл(x*b/a), где x - количество пройденных по стороне a точек

Comment: Ну я собственно это и имел ввиду :)

Answer (score 2):

Если вывод на консоль. Можно отталкиваться от того сколько символов * печатать в текущей строке. Для этого узнаем тангенс нужного угла http://www.neive.by.ru/trigonometrija/trfun.html
Далее печатаем нужное количество символов исходя из формулы: N-текущей строки помноженной на тангенс угла.
Пример если стороны A=4 и B=4, то тангенс = 1. Далее по шагам:

1@

2@@

3@@@

4@@@@

Answer (score 2):

Интересная задача=)

Могу предложить несколько вариантов. Я напишу упрощённые:

1. Пусть будет переменная, ограничивающая текущую сторону - ширина текущей стороны. Как тока итератор цикла будет равен оной переменной, выводим перенос строки, увеличиваем ширину (для следующей строки) и итератор цикла обнуляем. После оной проверки выводим звёздочки=) Цикл завершится как только ширина треугольника будет больше предельной для цикла.
2. Цикл будет большой - количество итераций как символов в квадрате. (n*n) Пока остаток от деления итератора на ширину будет меньше результата этого же деления, выводим звёздочку. Если остаток 0 - перенос строки.
3. Можно с флагами методом конечных автоматов=) Бесконечный цикл for, флаг рисования строки, флаг переноса строки, флаг завершения. И их переключение: рисовать строку, перенести строку-рисовать строку-...-завершить цикл. Тут развернуться можно хорошо. Если добавить тригонометрию, то хоть по трём точкам треугольники рисуй.

Если нужные не равнобедренные треугольники, то либо коэффициенты, либо несколько звёздочек за раз=)
Думаю, есть и иные варианты.

Answer (score 1):

Это решается ограничением прохода цикла левее и ниже линии y=kx+b, если прямой угол слева внизу и еще двумя линиями которые являются катетами треугольника.

Answer (score -1):

Можно еще матрицу использовать n * m, где m и n - стороны треугольника) Ниже главной диагонали, включая и её, будет " * ", а выше " ") как раз и цикл for задействован)) ну эт так вариант к слову))

Answer (score -1):

```
    var lines = 4;
    var star, space;
    for(var curLine = 1; curLine<=lines; curLine++)
    {
        space = lines - curLine;
        star = curLine * 2 - 1;
        drawLine(space, star, " ", "*");
    }

    function drawLine(cntTabs,  cntSymbols, tab, symbol)
    {
        var tabs = symbols = "";
        for(var i = 0; i<cntTabs; i++)
        {
            tabs += tab;
        }
        for(var i = 0; i<cntSymbols; i++)
        {
            symbols += symbol;
        }
        console.log(tabs + symbols);
    }
```

Comment: *"Код просьба не кидать."*

Answer (score -1):

Ну рисуешь на бумаге несколько треугольников и смотришь.

```
2
*
**

3
*
**
***

4
*
**
***
****
```

В i'й строке i звёздочек. Ну и делаем 2 вложенных цикла for - получается треугольник.

```
function triangle(n) {
  var res="";

  for (var q=1; q<=n; ++q) {
    for (var w=1; w<=q; ++w) {
      res += "*";
    }
    res += "\n";
  }

  return res;
}
```

Comment: *"Код просьба не кидать."*